# Global Education Indicators - dataset

Tags: data-request, education-economics

I've been looking for a dataset with a single education indicator by country so I can rank/compare them but I haven't found anything.

Already seen Unesco and Worldbank data but info is too much for what I really need at this point. Also had a look at the  Human Development Index (HDI)  but this is a composite statistic of life expectancy, education, and income per capita indicators so my analysi will be obscured by other elements.

I just need (for now) to be able to say for example Japan > Spain or Canada ranks 10th worldwide.

Does anyone have any idea as where I can download (if exists) this data set? API can work too. Ideally info comes with country iso code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Average years of education? http://datatopics.worldbank.org/Education/wDataQuery/QProjections.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can use the PISA study from OECD. It evaluates the skills and knowledge in reading, mathematics and sciene of 15-year-old students. PISA does not combine these results, but commentators do so sometimes.

The most recent results are from 2012, you can find an overview of the rankings [here](https://www.oecd.org/pisa/keyfindings/pisa-2012-results-overview.pdf). These rankings are composited from various tabels you can download using the links at page 297 from [this document](https://www.oecd.org/pisa/keyfindings/pisa-2012-results-volume-I.pdf).
Results of 2009 are available in a xls-file. Scroll down [this artcile](https://www.theguardian.com/news/datablog/2010/dec/07/world-education-rankings-maths-science-reading) to download.

Comment: hi this is pdf - do you have link to the raw data?

Comment: @Altons I can not find a xls-file for 2012, but I added some links where you can download the scores on reading, mathematics and science sepperatly. The composite xls-file is available for 2009, so I added it too.

Answer (score 2):

kaggle.com actually has a dataset that fits what you are looking for. The data set is called ["Education Statistics"](https://www.kaggle.com/theworldbank/education-statistics).

From the preview of the data, it seems like you cant do much with it, however you can rank countries by educational achievement and enrollment as done here [here](https://www.kaggle.com/pjoshi15/d/theworldbank/education-statistics/data-exploration-world-education).

hope this helps